# enter key with shift key running several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(enter key && shift key) running several times in j query.Need Help.Thanks in advance.

```
<textarea id = 'text' rows='4' cols='50' style = 'width: 50%;height:15%;' onkeypress = "go('6','5')" placeholder = 'Enter Post....'></textarea>;


function go(a,b){
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text').keypress(function (e) {   
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
            alert(a);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert(b);
        }
    }); 
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Since you've already applied inline `onkeypress` event, you don't need to apply `.keypress()` event again inside your `go` function.</s>

```
function go(a,b){
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
        alert(a);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert(b);
    }
}
```

---

It's because you've nested `keypress` call when `.keypress()` event has been applied inside inline `onkeypress`, so the best solution is  to remove the inline `onkeypress` event, you can just use `.keypress()` to achieve your goal:

```
$('#text').keypress(function (e) {   
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
        alert(a);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert(b);
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eM9DR/)**

Comment: fine sir but i want the values of a and b which i get from the parameter. Now how i can get the values of a and b?

Comment: No sir i need to get the values from html part any alternative way do u have?

Comment: You can assigned _the values from html part_ to these variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
<textarea id = 'text' rows='4' cols='50' style = 'width: 50%;height:15%;' placeholder = 'Enter Post....'></textarea>;


 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text').keypress(function (e) {   
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
            alert(a);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert(b);
        }
    }); 
 });
```

The ready() call will set up a keypress listener for your textarea.  No need to separately define an onkeypress attribute in the HTML.

Or, if you want to keep the onkeypress attribute instead of using $.keypress, it would look like:

```
<textarea id = 'text' rows='4' cols='50' style = 'width: 50%;height:15%;' onkeypress = "go('6','5')" placeholder = 'Enter Post....'></textarea>;


function go(a,b){
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
        alert(a);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert(b);
    }
}
```

The $.ready() function is run when the document is done loading.  That isn't necessary here because you're only defining a function (you don't need to wait for the document to be ready to define a function).  The $.keypress() function creates a keypress listener.  It isn't necessary here because you're already adding a listener using the onkeypress attribute.  So, all you're left with is the function that is called by your onkeypress code.

Comment: fine sir but i want the values of a and b which i get from the parameter. Now how i can get the values of a and b?

Comment: I added an alternative form of the solution.  See the second part of the answer.